# ExtJS 4.2.1 Different CSS Mask for loading indication and Modal Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I am working on a ExtJS 4.2.1 application which contains lot of alerts and Ajax call.

I found out that the same CSS class for the mask (.x-mask)is used for the loading and the modal mask when showing windows modally.

How can I use different behaviors for these two different things?

Problem:

1. For Modal window i need to get the red as a background color
2. For Loading mask i need to get the green as a background color

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both of loading and modal is using the same mask . I use the hack to solve the issue.
use the below css.

```
div.x-message-box + div.x-mask {
background: red;
}
```

You could use the sibling selector to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For loadMask, use [maskCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask-cfg-maskCls) to change mask style

Comment: Solution i've been looking for